# Build Electron for different environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, electron-builder

Ahoy,

I have an electron app where I currently manually edit an URL in one of my files, depending on which environment (dev, prod, test) I wish to build for. However I would rather like to define that in my script so I don't have to rewrite the URL every time (e.g. electron-builder -w --x64 --ia32 --test or something like that).

As far as I can tell it is possible to have different build files (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1109), but I can't quite figure how the setup should be, and furthermore I can't figure how to get the attributes from the build files (e.g. build/publish/url). It seems possible to get icon and name (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/639), but not url?

```
package.json

    {... ,
      "build":{
        ... ,
        "publish":[{
          ... ,
          "url": "https://my.website.url" <--- Change on build and fetchable in code?
        }],
      }
    }
```

I'm sorry if I have missed anything - I consider writing an explicit tutorial somewhere once I've got a hang of this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a (albeit a bit hack'ish imo) solution which I will use for now.

I simply added "--c.extraMetadata.productName=dev-" (and test instead of dev for the test build) to the build script, and then in my code i would check which environment that had been prepended to the build, and switch the URL accordingly. The good thing about this approach is that now I can also see which environment the .exe file is pointing at!

I'm still convinced that the "correct" way is having multiple YAML files, like Rhayene suggests, but the approach above just seems much easier and more directly controlled.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are not very elegant, but can still help:

**Prepare different configuration files beforehand**

Have different configuration YAML prepared and copy them to `electron-builder.yml` before building, depending on your platform or flavour.

**Create the build configuration dynamically**

This works better for more complicated settings:

Prepare a YAML or something else that contains all configurations that are true for every platform and a mock-value (or leave it empty) for the one you want to change at build time. I use a YAML file for this, because I can copy paste this into the `electron-builder.yml` in case I want something new, but you know best what you need.

Before building you run a node script that:

- optionally deletes the old `electron-builder.yml` from the previous build if present
- reads the prepared config file
- replaces the mock-value(s) with the real information in the read data
- writes the `electron-builder.yml` with the modified data

Your npm script would then look like `node prepareYml.js && electron-builder`.